# SSRS Two font colors in a single string value

Tags: report, ssrs-2008, builder

I am trying to modify the font color of a specific word in my values. What kind of expression could I write that would target this word and style the font to be red? I've heard of modifying the placeholder to accept HTML but I'm not sure this will help.

The value is made up from a case in the dataset that pulls from two tables that have gender so: "(consumer gender) | (caretaker gender)"

Possible values would be: **Male | Male, Male | Female, Missing | Male, Missing | Female, Missing | Missing ….etc**

What I'm trying to do is just target the "Missing" values and change the font color to red. Any way to do this? I've tried modifying the font color expression but only can figure out ways to modify the whole string as opposed to just that one word.

Comment: I am not sure just some particular text can be with particular color, as far as i know ssrs works with cell/text box and not just a particular text inside that text box.

Alternative: Anyhow your values are coming form 2 columns, how about you put 2 columns next to each other and remove border from then so that they will look like one column but in background 2 have columns (i.e 2 cells in a row) and then on cell you could add your logic of missing then red else black

Comment: To clarify, the data you are receiving from the dataset is in that format of _gender | gender_?  If so, it will probably work best if you do something to split the data on that "|" symbol and put each half into placeholders that can each have their own font colors.

Comment: Yeah I figured that's probably the avenue I have to go through unfortunately I work in a government office which means I have to go through all kinds of approval to modify the dataset >.>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but it's a bit of a pain..

I used a quick dataset to demo the results built from the following SQL

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (textData varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Male | Male'), ('Male | Female'), ('Missing | Male'), ('Missing | Female'), ('Missing | Missing')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

The column we will use is just called `textData`

Start with an empty cell.
In the empty cell, double click to get a cursor, right-click inside the cell and choose "Create Placeholder"
Right-click the placeholder and set it's expression to somethign like...

```
=TRIM(LEFT(Fields!textData.Value, InStr(Fields!textData.Value, "|") -1))
```

This will get the text from the left side from the pipe symbol. Click OK to get back to designer. click just after the new placeholder and type the pipe symbol (with spaces if required).

Next right click after the pipe symbol and add another placeholder. This time we will use an expression to get the right side of the pipe symbol.

```
=TRIM(MID(Fields!textData.Value, InStr(Fields!textData.Value, "|")+1 ))
```

Now we've got the data displaying, select the first placeholder and set its `color` property to

```
=IIF(TRIM(LEFT(Fields!textData.Value, InStr(Fields!textData.Value, "|") -1)) = "Missing", "Red", Nothing)
```

repeat for the second placeholder this time using this expression.

```
=IIF(TRIM(MID(Fields!textData.Value, InStr(Fields!textData.Value, "|")+1 )) = "Missing", "Red", Nothing)
```

IN my simple design, the left column shows the original unaltered data from the dataset, the right column contains out two placeholders with colors.
The final output looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Apologies to Steve-o 169 ! I only just saw that his comment describes exactly this approach!

Comment: Hi sorry for the late comment I didn't even see this until today. This works perfectly except the left trim seems to come up with an #error on almost every value and it seems to be completely random, it doesn't happen on any specific values but just allows some values to pass and #errors out others. I'll do more digging myself and see if there's something in the query doing this maybe.

Comment: Never mind I went back to the query found out that there was a weird rollup done on this query just modified your code with some iif statements to take into account for the pipe not existing works fine thanks again.